# Did django compile views.py everytime a view is requested?

Tags: python, django, class, view

i'm working on a django project and in views.py i need to use an external class for doing some stuff.
If i declare the reference of the class, like:

```
class = MyClass()
```

in the top of views.py. Did django need to instantiate the class everytime a view is requested? Or it uses the same instance for all the views(this is what i want)?

What i want to achive is to have this external class that is very slow to initialize (4-5 seconds), and use it in one view for all the users... like:

```
def myview(request):
    # ... some code ...
    output = class.doSomeStuff()
    # .................
```

Comment: What does that class do, why wouldn't you properly cache initialized data instead.

Comment: @iklinac it loads and control input and output for [this](https://github.com/NicGian/SentITA) that is a model for sentiment analysis in italian. When i only add the import for this class, django is unable to serve pages and there is no activity in the logs of apache.

Answer (score -1):

When a python project is run, every module is parsed once and cached.

If you declare this class instance at the top level of your module (your file), you will have one instance of YourClass as a module attribute.

So this should be fine.